# How to differentiate step responses of 1st-order and 2nd-order systems?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, control-theory

How can one determine if a system is of 1<sup>st</sup> or 2<sup>nd</sup> order by merely looking at the step response of the system or device?

One can easily spot an underdamped response straightaway by the overshoots, but the step response of first-order and second-order critically damped and overdamped systems look very similar.

Is there a key to differentiating these responses from a graph?

**Figures**

First order step response
[image]

Second order step response
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the curve has an inflection point, then the system is second order. Otherwise, I am afraid that there is little you can do.

Answer (score -1):

Over damped responses hit an aysmptote below the $100%$ maximum signal mark. Which is the mark that under damped systems orbit and critically damped systems go to.

Comment: This is false.  All damped responses go to equilibrium.